# QR code reader for OS X 10.6?

Tags: snow-leopard, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a QR code reader that doesn't utilize iSight but instead, allows me to take a screenshot of a portion of the screen which it will then scan for and detect the QR code. I'm having trouble finding one because most QR code readers for mac that I can see uses the iSight which is not what I am after.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to a native OS X application is an online QR code reader, such as

- [ZXing](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx)
- [miniQR](http://miniqr.com/reader.php) (also allows you to use your iSight camera)
- [Online Barcode Reader](http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/) (also decodes barcodes; an added plus)
- [Patrick Wied QR Generator](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/qrgen/) (also allows you to create QR codes).

All of these services are free. To use them, all you need to do is upload a screenshot, and the website will return the result.

Comment: +1 for Zxing, which can be compiled as a CLI application.

Answer (score 0):

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/quickmark-qr-code-reader/id412378487?mt=12

you can try ihis.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.